# Is there a Holder inequality for vector-valued functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, holder-inequality, bochner-spaces

Suppose
$$\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}.$$
The usual Holder's inequality for scalar valued functions says that if $f \in L^p$ and $g \in f^q$, then $fg \in L^r$ and
$$\|fg\|_{L^r} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}.$$

I am looking if any analogous statement holds for vector-valued $L^p$ spaces. For example, suppose $f \in L^p(0, T; L^u)$ (takes values in $L^u$) and $g \in L^q(0, T; L^v)$. Does Holder's inequality still apply? More specifically, is $fg \in L^r(0, T; L^w)$? If so, what is the requirement on $w$? Is it that
$$\frac{1}{w} = \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v}?$$
I could not find anything in my textbooks or online.

EDIT: Based on Nick's comment, I was able to write out
$$\|fg\|_{L^r} = \Big(\int_0^T\|fg\|_{L^w}^r\Big)^{1/r} \leq \Big(\int_0^T\|f\|_{L^u}^r\|g\|_{L^v}^r\Big)^{1/r}.$$
I am now working on bounding the above by the product of each integral and hence finish the proof.

Comment: If you write it out, it should be immediate. The conditions you have are correct. Do Holder in the spatial norm first and then in the time integral.

Comment: @Nick Thank you. Based on your suggestions I have edited my post. How would one apply Holder's inequality to the time integral?

Comment: In applying Holder exactly the same way. You’d have for $1/p+1/q=1/r$ that your last integral is at most $\Big(\int_0^T \|f(t)\|_u^pdt\Big)^{1/p}\Big(\int_0^T\|g(t)\|^q_vdt\Big)^{1/q}$

Comment: @Nick Ah I see, here we are viewing the integral as the $L^r$ norm of $\|f\|_{L^u}\|g\|_{L^v}$?

Comment: Yes,  precisely.